# PHP header redirects without www

Tags: php, html

```
header("Location: https:/index.php");
```

redirects the page to the `index.php` page but it redirects using `https://website.com` and I need to keep the `www.website.com`.

How can I keep the www in the redirect using a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to fetch the host name of your server so:

```
$hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ; 
header("Location: {$hostname}".);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try ..('location: http://www.website.com') ?

Comment: yes but my set sessions doesn't stay with the redirect to the  index page is dynamic.